# Find the last local git commit that is also present in/was pushed to upstream

Tags: git

Is there a way to get the last local Git commit that I also pushed on upstream?

To explain a little more: I would like the last local commit that was also pushed on upstream, not to be confused by the last upstream commit which is not always also local(because you can bring upstream commits using git fetch and the fetched commits are not local anymore).

I understand that one could make an algorithm that looks over the upstream commits and over the local commits, does some comparisons and determine which was the last local commit i.e. that appears when `git log`ing and is also present in upstream but a git command that gives this information would be very handy.

Comment: Remote-tracking branches are local references that track what was pulled or pushed. Isn't `origin/master` what you're looking for?

Comment: No, because one could use `git fetch` and commits that are not local will be present inside `origin/master`. What I would like to have is the last commit in `origin/master` that is also present locally, in `master`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time that would be

```
git merge-base origin/master master
```

(substituting whatever branch name for `master`).

The major exception would be if either the local or remote branch has been rewritten, so that they don't have any common commits.  (Well... they'd still have common history probably, but nothing you'd think of as "part of' the branch.)  In that case, there's not a good answer other than to eyeball it.

Comment: When you say that the `branch has been rewritten` are you referring to the possibility of someone force pushing to `origin/master`?

Comment: @JacobKrieg - If the remote was rewritten, then someone forced pushed to it.  If the local was rewritten, that could be lots of things but usually would be a rebase (and means that the local would need to be force pushed).